# Get MaximumEntropyModelParameters from model in ML.Net

Tags: c#, ml.net

Create pipeline:

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("output")
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "pixels"))
                    .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LbfgsMaximumEntropy(labelColumnName: "output", featureColumnName: "Features"))
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));
```

Load model:

```
DataViewSchema modelSchema = null;
               var model = mlContext.Model.Load("Data.zip", out modelSchema);

var originalModelParameters = ((ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<CalibratedModelParametersBase<MaximumEntropyModelParameters, PlattCalibrator>>)model).Model.SubModel; //ERROR

MaximumEntropyModelParameters originalModelParameters =
    ((ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>)model).Model as MaximumEntropyModelParameters; //ERROR
```

Error message:
`Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain'1[Microsoft.ML.Transforms.KeyToValueMappingTransformer]" in type "Microsoft.ML.ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer'1[System.Object]"`.

Comment: Have you tried casting to `IPredictionTransformer` instead of `ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer`?

Comment: Also, I'm not too sure if it will do that correctly with the last transformer being the KeyToValue transform instead of it being the trainer.

Comment: IPredictionTransformer - Error(

Comment: MapKeyToValue needs to be saved

Comment: Removing "MapKeyToValue" I get the same error.